# can I create multiple Google play developer account with same credit/debit card?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

Currently I am having one google play developer account.I want to Open New Account with same debit card which I used for my current account.all my details will be same as my old account.

In Short,can I create multiple Google play developer account with same credit/debit card?
Is it legal?

I also want to know that, If one of my account gets banned,will it affect second one,since both are created using same debit card.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question - it is a question about google's terms and conditions.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, just be warned that if one is suspended, there's a good chance that both will br

Comment: thank you @phong have Experienced such type of Suspension?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not buy multiple accounts with the same Debit/Credit card.
Whenever one account is suspended/terminated then any other accounts with the same card will have the same actions taken.

Some days ago, a friend bought a console account, then after some time he bought another friend an account using same card. When the new friend's account was terminated, the first account was also terminated.